# Javascript/PHP/MySQL Change <select> options depending on the selected option of another <select> element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have 2  elements in my form. I want to change the options on the second one whenever i select an option in the first one.

For example, my first select element contains teams and the second one contains the members. The data is contained in a MySQL database. Whenever I choose a team, I want the options of the second select element to show only members of the team selected.

I don't know if this could be done using PHP only or using javascript. It would be great if you could show me a piece of code that could work in this scenario.

Thanks,
-Paul

Comment: Hi Paul. What is it you are looking for? A pre-written piece of code that will do this for you? Here on Stack Overflow, we like questions :) What is your question?

Comment: sorry about that. i need a piece of code that would work in my scenario. thanks :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for updating your question, it's much better :) I think you'll be lucky to find a detailed answer though, as there are a lot of parts to your request. Are you developing the full stack yourself? It might be best to break the task down into smaller parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, and which way is best depends a bit on your capabilities.

The best way, as others have said, is to setup some Ajax functionality to contact a separate php script and supply it with the value for the first dropdown, from which it will return the list that should be put into the second dropdown. The javascript/ajax code on the original page would then do the actual processing to load the data that the script supplied into the dropdown.

Since it sound like you are a bit new to the javascript arena, doing things with Ajax might be a bit too much of a jump to bite off. You could solve this without Ajax by populating javascript arrays with values that you load in from MySQL while PHP is compiling the page. Then when the first dropdown is changed, you could populate the second dropdown with the values from the corresponding array.

The second approach is not ideal (primarily in that it means you are loading a lot of stuff that will likely never get used), but it will be easier to understand while you are learning. And a side benefit is that it will perform slightly faster than an Ajax solution, because it doesn't have to incur the transfer overhead of retrieving the data from the server.

Comment: "might be a bit too much of a jump to bite off." - mixing your metaphors! There is an episode of "yes prime minister" that does the same :->

Comment: thanks jeffrey. this is clear enough for me. i was able to find samples in google with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need Javascript to do this as the processing to update the web page is on the browser. An Ajax call to a PHP script to fetch the details is required when the user selects the team.

Comment: could you point me to a sample code on how to do this? i have a very limited knowledge of ajax and i need an example to quickly solve this problem. thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @PaulAdrianPena - Do you know Javascript? If so you should be able to do the update bit. If not you need to learn Javascript. As to Ajax google JQuery/Ajax. That should give you some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot access a database directly from a browser. You need some server-side scripting, for example PHP.

Answer (score 0):

[Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is the solution to your problems. Ajax allows you to retrieve information easily,fast and without having to refresh your page.
You can create an event that will send information your php file(where you will process everything) via Ajax  and then get back your result and put in your select statement

Answer (score 0):

just a quick demo

```
<select id = "select1">
    <option value = "1"></option>
    ...
</select>

<select id = "select2">
</select>
```

then with javascript (i love the way jquery does ajax):

```
$('#select1').change(function(){

    var sendmeover = $('#select1').val();

    $.post("yourphpscript.php",{ 
        sendingthiswithpost: sendmeover
    },
    //and here is the responce
    function(data){
        $('#select2').html(''+data+'');
    });
})//end select change
```

then your php (yourphpscript.php):

```
<?php
    $variablesent = $_REQUEST['sendingthiswithpost'];

    //here is where you would run an sql query and ech your results

    echo $variablesent
?>
```

let me know if i missed anything and ill fix it, did this pretty briefly. note: you will need to consruct your `<option>` tags in the php